# Legend for selected functions only

Tags: pgfplots, legend

In my plot, there are 6-7 `\addplot[]` entries but I want legend for only one of those functions. How can I do that? I tried `\addlegendentry` after the function I wish to have a legend for but it creates a legend corresponding to the first one.

Comment: Hi Baptu88, welcome to the site! You can add `forget plot` to the plots that you want to exclude from the legend.

Comment: I solved it by including `legend entries={My Function}` and `\addlegendimage{no markers, mycolor}` in the `\begin axis[]` part.

Comment: That also works. You have to be aware that with that approach, the style of the plot and the legend entry aren't linked any more, so if you change the color of the plot, the legend won't automatically reflect that.